# Are online retailers breaking EU/US law by using user's log-in information to charge different prices without explicitly notifying them?

Tags: united-states, internet, gdpr, european-union, commerce

I am aware that in most places firms are generally allowed to price discriminate, i.e. offer different prices for the same product to different customers based on personal characteristics. For example, students getting book discounts, retirees cheaper fare etc. However, is it legal in the EU/USA to do so without explicitly stating that's their policy and/or informing you they use your data to do so?

**Context:**

Very recently I tried to purchase an eBook from Amazon.com, form the US store while being in the EU because the local Amazon.nl did not offer an eBook version, only hard-copy, and I made previously purchases from Amazon.com while being here in such situation without problems. However, the listed price changed (and increased) after I logged in into the store and made a purchase.

I contacted the Amazon customer support about this and their first response was that this was due to different taxes or just natural price variation over time. However, I noticed that even before I logged in into amazon.com the amazon.com was displaying the Netherlands as my region (I also do not use VPN or any service to hide my IP address). Furthermore, since I accidentally purchased it I could see that the pre-tax changed, not VAT. Another suspicious thing was that only the price of eBook version changed. In addition, after their customer support response I decided to run an experiment and log-in/out multiple times and the price was changing always whenever I logged in or out.

I made a photographic and video evidence of this and after confronting the customer support with this evidence, they admitted that it is in fact log in status that determines my price and not region/time. In their response they stated:

> ... "I'm very sorry about the incorrect information you received. [referencing the previous incorrect claims about price changing due to my location or time variation through day]
>
> Please be informed that the change of price differs before you login and after you login onto our Kindle store using your Amazon account" ...

The text in [] are my clarifications.

However, this response made me wondering if this conduct is legal. The reason for that is that according to [GDPR explanation on EU website](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/dealing-with-customers/data-protection/data-protection-gdpr/index_en.htm) under GDPR company collecting my personal data and using it for automated decision making should inform me about that and have me agree to it. Amazon has an explanation page for how they use your data but they never mention individualized price hiking/price discrimination [explicitly](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=G7LUHQG6TKZRR4QQ) (or maybe they use language that legally covers such action as well that as an layman I can't understand). The same applies to their [user agreement](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202140280).

Furthermore, even though I currently reside in the EU I don't know if this would not fall outside GDPR and under the US law, and if so I would like to know what it would say about the situation.

Lastly, their response shows that they always had data which showed that price changed due to my log in and hence first time they misled me either intentionally or hopefully just due to some human error. What does US/EU law say about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason for that is that according to GDPR explanation on EU website under GDPR company collecting my personal data and using it for automated decision making should inform me about that and have me agree to it.

**Only if the basis for processing is consent.**

The GDPR provides 6 legal basis for data processing - consent is only one of them. If their basis for processing is any one of the other 5 then a) they don’t have to ask for consent and b) they don’t have to tell you about it.

In the context of Amazon with respect to a particular purchase, it's far more likely that the basis is "to fulfil a contractual obligation with the individual". Specifically, the price to be paid is clearly a fundamental part of the contract.

> Furthermore, even though I currently reside in the EU I don't know if this would not fall outside GDPR and under the US law, and if so I would like to know what it would say about the situation.

You are in the EU and they, Amazon are operating in the EU, the GDPR applies. US law also applies.

> Lastly, their response shows that they always had data which showed that price changed due to my log in and hence first time they misled me either intentionally or hopefully just due to some human error. What does US/EU law say about that?

Nothing - people can make mistakes without incurring legal liability. Only if the mistake rises to the level of negligence  or breach of contract are there any legal ramifications.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The last part is crystal clear, however I am not sure if I understand the first part (that is the paragraph under the sentence “only if the basis for processing is consent” - including the sentence itself). If they do not mention in their terms of service agreement they use my data for purpose of individually tailoring price did I gave them consent in some other implicit way? Also, do I understand correctly that the paragraph under that sentence means that for the purposes of making the purchase contract they can use my data however they want without my permission?

Comment: Lastly, the part in the middle is more or less clear but if both US and EU law applies at the same time what happens if they would be in conflict? Or rather is it that in such situations a person has a choice to apply either one of them?

Comment: @1muflon1 It's a common misunderstanding of GDPR that consent is required to process your data. It is actually the last resort, when the other five legal bases don't apply. For example, if you open a bank account with $100 000 in cash the bank is going to file a money laundering report. It doesn't need your consent because complying with the law is a sufficient reason.

Comment: Per Article 22, if the automated decision is lawful because (A) it "is necessary for entering into, or performance of, a contract between the data subject and a data controller" or (B) "is based on the data subject’s explicit consent", " the data controller shall implement suitable measures to safeguard the data subject’s rights and freedoms and legitimate interests, at least the right to obtain human intervention on the part of the controller, to express his or her point of view and to contest the decision".

Comment: @Lag and richardb thanks for clarifications now its more clear but even if they can do it without my consent shouldn't they mention that they are doing it somewhere on their site or is it allowed to in such cases do that without any notice? Because, as mentioned in the first paragraph of my original question I am mainly interested in knowing whether they can do it without telling customers in advance they are doing so

Comment: “they don’t have to tell you about it” – not so sure. The GDPR Art 13/14 right to be informed exists independently of the Art 6 legal basis, and just elaborates the more general transparency principle in Art 5(1)(a). I also doubt whether this instance of automated decision making is actually *necessary*, as compared to e.g. a credit check. However, I have doubts that changing the price only depending on login status is a case of automated decision making in the sense of the GDPR. This might run afoul of consumer protection laws, though.

Comment: @amon I also think this might fall under consumer protection law not GDPR. In the UK, I think this would be 'bait advertising' per "Commercial practices which are in all circumstances considered unfair", Schedule 1, The Consumer Protection from Unfair Trading Regulations 2008. The seller isn't allowed to lure people in with a lower price than what the seller will allow the person to buy the product for.

Comment: @Lag does EU have some similar consumer protection law as UK?

Comment: @1muflon1 I believe that particular rule is EU-wide. You could contact your national consumer association for advice. In the UK that would be the Trading Standards office. https://ec.europa.eu/info/policies/consumers/consumer-protection/our-partners-consumer-issues/national-consumer-bodies_en

Comment: @Lag it would be bait if the logged in price were higher but not if it were lower. The OP just said they were different

Comment: @DaleM the logged in price actually was higher - hence why I also complained to their customer service- I did not realized that wasn’t clear - I edited my question and I would really like to apologize for not making that clear

Comment: From the context and the phrase "price hiking" I inferred that the price increases. In my experience people don't complain or investigate when the price at checkout is lower than they expect.